# How to add a TXT record to your DNS referencing Sonatype JIRA Ticket on AWS Route53?

Tags: maven-3, sonatype

Recently I wanted to add my jar to Maven Central Repository.
I have raised a ticket to the community.

They wanted to verify whether I'm the owner of the domain. So I was doing this activity. They asked me to

"Add a TXT record to your DNS referencing this JIRA ticket: << Jira Link>>"

Go to [AWS Route 53 Hosted Zone page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home#hosted-zones:)
Select your domain and add a TXT record with the value as your Ticket link.

Now fire below command to verify.

dig -t txt << domain name >>

Eg: dig -t txt example.com

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to your DNS provider of choice and add a TXT record containing the id (ex: OSSRH-XXXX) of the jira ticket.
2. Wait until Search Engines index it. You can check your TXT record on free site https://dnslookup.online/txt.html
3. After that in issue comment ask for someone from Sonatype to reply.

If everything is Ok, you will get an answer with a list of next steps

Comment: The search engine doesn't index DNS, these are different protocols.

Answer (score 4):

[cosic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857829/839733)'s answer is ambiguous because "*add a TXT record containing the id*" could mean adding the URL of the JIRA ticket, or just the ticket number.

To be perfectly clear, **add the complete URL to the Sonatype JIRA ticket.** How to add a TXT record depends on your provider; [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/317/2237/how-do-i-add-txtspfdkimdmarc-records-for-my-domain) is the link for Namecheap. If there’s an option to put in a custom TTL, put 7 days; if not, leave it at automatic.

Then run `dig -t TXT com.mydomain`, and in the `ANSWER SECTION`, you should see a line referencing the JIRA ticket. It may take some time for the change to propagate through the DNS servers.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
com.mydomain.       1798    IN  TXT "https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-xxx"
```

Comment in the Sonatype ticket with the output.